# Web RTC setLocalDescription always fails on iOS 14

Tags: ios, webrtc, sdp

I'm working on a small web rtc framework on iOS and having difficulties with setRemoteDescription. I wrote my own SDP parser/writer and checked every aspect of it. Even thought the SDP looks fine, it always fails:

```
let sessionDescription = RTCSessionDescription(type: .answer, sdp: sdp)
pc.setRemoteDescription(sessionDescription) { error in
        if let error = error {
            // Always fails with "SessionDescription is NULL"
        }
        else {
           ...
        }
    }
```

The error is:

```
   Error Domain=org.webrtc.RTC_OBJC_TYPE(RTCPeerConnection) Code=-1 "SessionDescription is NULL." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=SessionDescription is NULL.}
```

Here is the po of sessionDescription:

```
v=0
o=clientlib 10000 1 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=-
t=0 0
a=ice-lite
a=fingerprint:sha-512 C9:CE:DF:4A:9A:35:95:6F:94:BF:14:82:50:A2:73:97:54:97:5D:1D:7A:C1:B0:31:A7:44:92:4A:A5:F1:ED:22:EB:A1:D2:22:7B:6F:76:96:F1:95:97:2E:49:4E:B1:A4:61:AF:D9:9E:82:55:C8:55:EA:6E:2B:56:BE:55:C4:3C
a=msid-semantic: WMS *
a=group:BUNDLE 0
m=video 7 96 97 98 99 100 101 127 123 125 122 124 100
c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
a=rtpmap:100 VP8/90000
a=fmtp:100 x-google-start-bitrate=1000
a=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:rtp-stream-id
a=extmap:6 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:repaired-rtp-stream-id
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:8 http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-avtext-framemarking-07
a=extmap:13 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=extmap:14 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=setup:active
a=mid:0
a=recvonly
a=ice-ufrag:jf3q436s5vhriv09
a=ice-pwd:s4sft4792k6gv49ml9psq9cantjt4hqj
a=candidate:udpcandidate 1 udp 1076558079 34.199.191.112 25738 typ host
a=candidate:tcpcandidate 1 tcp 1076302079 34.199.191.112 24688 typ host tcptype passive
a=end-of-candidates
a=ice-options:renomination
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
```

Peer connection (pc) was created in a usual way:

```
let config = RTCConfiguration()
config.sdpSemantics = .unifiedPlan
    
let constraints = RTCMediaConstraints(mandatoryConstraints: nil, optionalConstraints: nil)
pc = peerConnectionFactory.peerConnection(with: config, constraints: constraints, delegate: self)
```

Is there any way to get more information about what's wrong with the sdp other than "SessionDescription is NULL"?
Any hints, ideas are appreciated.

Comment: How did you resolve it? I'm facing the same issue wrote my own encoder/decoder, Actually checked it on both sides was the same, but I'm getting the same error. I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple possible issues

Your `m` line contains RTP PayloadTypes that aren't defined. Change it to `m=video 100`

*m line was the issue, see comments for discussion. candidate string isn't actually an issue*

Your candidate line might be wrong. I don't believe foundation can be a string? I need to check the spec though. Instead of `udpcandidate` and `tcpcandidate` do `1` and `2`. Refer to the spec for the actual algorithim to generate that value.

Comment: Thanks for the input, m line is indeed a problem. Foundation can be a string though

Comment: nice! Edited my answer in case anyone hits in the future